# Advice: TSDB storage engine in DolphinDB should perform deduplication based on both sortColumns and partitionColumns

Tags: sorting, duplicates, time-series, dolphindb

Currently, the TSDB storage engine performs deduplication based on sortColumns, which may cause unintended data overwrites. It is recommended that the deduplication strategy should be based on both sortColumns and partitionColumns, or that sortColumns should by default include partitionColumns.

The following is my script, which is supposed to return two rows of data but only returns one due to data overwrites.

```
d_db1 = database("", HASH,[SYMBOL,20])
d_db2 = database("", VALUE, 2010.01M..2030.01M)

d_db = database("dfs://test",COMPO, [d_db1, d_db2],engine="TSDB")

day_col_names = `time`instrument`factor`value
day_col_types = [DATE,SYMBOL,SYMBOL,FLOAT]

factor_day_table = table(1:0, day_col_names, day_col_types)

d_db.createPartitionedTable(factor_day_table, `factor_day, `factor`time, compressMethods={time:`delta}, sortColumns=`instrument`time,keepDuplicates=LAST)

t1 = table(2010.01.01 as time, `test as instrument, `open as factor, 1 as value)
t2 = table(2010.01.01 as time, `test as instrument, `low as factor, 1 as value)
t = loadTable("dfs://test", `factor_day)

t.append!(t1)
t.append!(t2)

select * from t
```

Answer (score 0):

The sortColumns parameter mainly serves for 3 purposes: data indexing, data deduplication, and data sorting (not targeting the overall data). sortColumns and partitionColumns are mutually independent. You can choose to specify partitionColumns in sortColumns or not. Your script returns only one row of data because sortColumns is `instrument`time. To return two rows of data, you can set sortColumns to factor`instrument`time.